# Is it possible to connect more than two devices in Android Studio's Bluetooth emulator? If not, is there another emulator that allows that?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-emulator

So I've been using the Android Studio emulator to debug my Bluetooth app (a godsend as I don't have a lot of Android devices available). The app (already in use on field for nearly a decade) supports having up to 4 devices (one act as a "server", the other three needing to pair and connect to that one as "clients").

Bluetooth in emulation works (albeit a bit unstable and requiring the occasional reboot) with two devices, but when I add a third one, it goes wild: on pairing, devices flip names constantly, Bluetooth turns off on its own and I can't really pair more than one on each device (and that's before I get my app involved - this is all just in the "Connected Devices" system setting).

I wonder whether that relates to the fact that all of them have the same Bluetooth address (DA:4C:10:DE:17:00), or if it is a limitation of this emulator (which seems to be quite recent and only works with recent Android version). If the later, is there any other way/tool to test such a 4-phone scenario (other than having 4 physical devices)?